# how to handle spl token transfer as a delegate

Tags: spl-token

account a has giving account b approval as a delegate to x tokens, how do i transfer x - 1 tokens from account a to account c, after the delegate transaction has been approved.
i keep trying with transferChecked but im running into an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publicKey') at getSigners

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [Solana Playground example](https://beta.solpg.io/657f6d4afb53fa325bfd0c64) of transferring tokens using a delegate.

Once you approve a delegate for a token account, you can submit a token transfer using the delegate as the "owner" of the token account. The delegate can transfer up to the approved amount.

```
import { Connection, Keypair, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  createMint,
  mintTo,
  createAccount,
  transfer,
  approve,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

// Playground wallet
const payer = pg.wallet.keypair;

// Connection to devnet cluster
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

// Transaction signature returned from sent transaction
let transactionSignature: string;

// Authority that can mint new tokens
const mintAuthority = pg.wallet.publicKey;

// Create new mint account using `createMint` helper function
const mint = await createMint(
  connection,
  payer, // payer
  payer.publicKey, // mint authority
  null, // freeze authority
  2 // decimals
);

console.log(
  "Mint Account: ",
  `https://explorer.solana.com/address/${mint.toString()}?cluster=devnet`
);

// Random keypair to use as owner of Token Account
const randomKeypair = new Keypair();
// Create Token Account for random keypair
const sourceTokenAccount = await createAccount(
  connection,
  payer, // Payer to create Token Account
  mint, // Mint Account address
  randomKeypair.publicKey // Token Account owner
);

// Create Token Account for Playground wallet
const destinationTokenAccount = await createAccount(
  connection,
  payer, // Payer to create Token Account
  mint, // Mint Account address
  payer.publicKey // Token Account owner
);

// Mint tokens to sourceTokenAccount, owned by randomKeypair
transactionSignature = await mintTo(
  connection,
  payer, // Transaction fee payer
  mint, // Mint Account address
  sourceTokenAccount, // Mint to
  mintAuthority, // Mint Authority address
  100 // Amount
);

console.log(
  "\nMint Tokens:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);

// Approve delegate, (playground wallet as delegate)
transactionSignature = await approve(
  connection,
  payer, // Transaction fee payer
  sourceTokenAccount, // Token Account to set delegate for
  payer.publicKey, // Delegate
  randomKeypair.publicKey, // Token Account owner
  100, // Amount delegated
  [randomKeypair] // Signer
);

console.log(
  "\nApprove Delegate:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);

// Transfer with delegate
transactionSignature = await transfer(
  connection,
  payer, // Transaction fee payer
  sourceTokenAccount, // Transfer from
  destinationTokenAccount, // Transfer to
  payer.publicKey, // Pass in delegate as owner
  100 // Amount
);

console.log(
  "\nTranfer with Delegate:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);
```